# Why does my code sometimes return undefined

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I am trying to display two numbers that are not the same but every time they turn out to be the same and sometimes it displays undefined. Is there any way to fix this?

```js
var usedCard = [0];
var columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
function columnBB(){
 if (usedCard.includes(columnB)){
  columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
  columnBB();
 }
 else {return columnB};
}
document.getElementById("B1").innerHTML = columnBB();
usedCard.push(columnB);
columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16)
document.getElementById("B2").innerHTML = columnBB();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="B1"></td>
<td id="B2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: run the code snippet multiple times

Answer (score 1):

You are using recursion. When the function calls itself it never returns because it will only call the else branch if the if branch is never called.  Remove the else and simply return and you should be good.

```js
var usedCard = [0];
var columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
function columnBB(){
 if (usedCard.includes(columnB)){
  columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16);
  columnBB();
 }
 return columnB;
}
document.getElementById("B1").innerHTML = columnBB();
usedCard.push(columnB);
columnB = Math.floor(Math.random()*16)
document.getElementById("B2").innerHTML = columnBB();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td id="B1"></td>
<td id="B2"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```